# Shiny Server - Active: inactive (dead)

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, shiny, shiny-server

Couple of days back I created an instance in AWS with CentOS - MySQL - R - Shiny-Server. The shiny-server is a free version. I loaded my app, data into MySQL.  My app ran without a glitche for two days.  Since yesterday afternoon, I am getting a "Failed to connect: message" from Safari.  When I explored I figured out why shiny-server got stopped, I got the following message:

```
systemctl status shiny-server -l
● shiny-server.service - ShinyServer
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/shiny-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2016-06-29 02:51:11 UTC; 35s ago
  Process: 3567 ExecStopPost=/usr/bin/sleep 5 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3565 ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/sleep 3 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3557 ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c /opt/shiny-server/bin/shiny-server --pidfile=/var/run/shiny-server.pid >> /var/log/shiny-server.log 2>&1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 3276 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jun 29 02:51:03 ip-172-31-8-158.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Starting ShinyServer...
Jun 29 02:51:11 ip-172-31-8-158.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Started ShinyServer.
```

When i checked the /var/log/shiny-server.log i am getting the following error.

```
^[[32m[2016-06-29 02:51:03.902] [INFO] shiny-server - ^[[39mShiny Server v1.4.2.786 (Node.js v0.10.40)
^[[32m[2016-06-29 02:51:03.903] [INFO] shiny-server - ^[[39mUsing pidfile /var/run/shiny-server.pid
^[[32m[2016-06-29 02:51:03.904] [INFO] shiny-server - ^[[39mUsing config file "/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf"
^[[31m[2016-06-29 02:51:03.940] [ERROR] shiny-server - ^[[39mError loading config: run_as directive appears too many times (/etc/shin$
^[[32m[2016-06-29 02:51:03.941] [INFO] shiny-server - ^[[39mShutting down worker processes
```

When I removed the comment on the PIDfile line got the following error:

```
Job for shiny-server.service failed because a configured resource limit was exceeded.
```

Going by examples here at SO i tried doing the following:

Commented out the line `PIDfile=/var/run/shiny-server.pid` and changed the `Type=forking` from `simple` in the /etc/systemd/system/shiny-server.service file.  Stop, start, restart shiny-server with commenting out, commenting in the pid file didn't seem to work.

Tried adding a link `ln -s shiny-server.service /systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants` but got a message file already exits.  Not sure how to start the server again.

Comment: I'm no AWS expert, but it sounds like you overtaxed your account in some way and it shut down the instance. Paying Amazon money may help, if you can figure out what to ask for in return.

Comment: @alistaire But my credit card is attached to my AWS account and the instance is running.  I tried stopping and starting the instances too...there are no warning messages.  I could log into to my account through ssh. However, I will check that once again.

Comment: Beyond me, then, sorry.